How to Add a New Menu Option Before "Show More Options" in Windows 11 Context Menu?
I'm currently working on a project that involves customizing the context menu in Windows 11. Specifically, I would like to add a new menu option that appears just before the "Show More Options" item.
I've been able to add new menu items to the context menu, but they always appear after click on "Show More Options." Is there a way to place my custom menu option before "Show More Options"?
Here's what I've tried so far:
Used the registry to add a new key under
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\SolankiTest
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\SolankiTest
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\SolankiTest

Set the position of my custom item using the Position value in the registry, but it still appears after click "Show More Options." and open new screen.
Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Also tried many time to update regedit also this all command are working but it will show after click on "Show More Options.".
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/restore-old-right-click-context-menu-in-windows-11/a62e797c-eaf3-411b-aeec-e460e6e5a82a
etc....
Found information from ChateGPT.
https://chatgpt.com/share/e65c31d4-ecfb-4837-a8bd-a8a18d0c23c5
Direct modifications to the simplified context menu (without needing to click "Show more options") is intentionally restricted by Microsoft to prevent clutter and improve performance. Advanced tools or scripts might be required for deeper customization which might not be officially supported or could potentially cause system issues.
Thank you.
